# AWS EMR - Apache Flink web client

Tags: emr, apache-flink

Is there a way to start Flink web client to allow job submissions if running using AWS EMR? 
I have downloaded FLink 1.1.2 and in old docs <1.0 I see references to `./bin/start-webclient.sh` which doesn't exist in my downloaded binary.

Is there a way to start this web client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's "web client" got removed as of `v1.0.0` and its functionality got embedded into `JobManager`s web frontend.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2978